# Android TextView being cut off by gravity=center

Tags: java, android

I'm displaying a lot of textviews in a linear layout and setting gravity to center causes the words to be cut off. I'm runnning a Nexus S in the emulator.

```
<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="585dp"
    android:layout_height="810dp"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    tools:layout_editor_absoluteX="8dp"
    tools:layout_editor_absoluteY="8dp">

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/TeamName4"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Team 2 Name"
        android:textAppearance="@android:style/TextAppearance.Theme"
        android:textSize="20sp"
        android:textStyle="bold|italic"/>

    <EditText
        android:gravity="center"
        android:id="@+id/TeamScore1"
        android:layout_width="40dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:ems="10"
        android:inputType="number" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/TeamName2"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:text="Team 2 Name"
        android:textAppearance="@android:style/TextAppearance.Theme"
        android:textSize="20sp"
        android:textStyle="bold|italic" />

    <EditText
        android:gravity="center"
        android:id="@+id/TeamScore2"
        android:layout_width="40dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:ems="10"
        android:inputType="numberSigned" />
```

That's a snippet of the code. I experience the same issue with all my other textViews. Any advice how to make the text appear in the center of the screen?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Don't use hardcoded height and width for linear layout

Use match_parent as height and width for LinearLayout for your particular code.

Always prefer to use match_parent or wrap_content, it will be helpful when your application runs on devices with different screen sizes

Go through below link for more understanding
https://developer.android.com/training/multiscreen/screensizes#TaskUseWrapMatchPar

Answer (score 0):

Modify your LinearLayout Properties like:

(It will make your text appear in the center of the screen)

```
<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="vertical">

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/TeamName4"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Team 2 Name"
        android:textAppearance="@android:style/TextAppearance.Theme"
        android:textSize="20sp"
        android:textStyle="bold|italic"/>
     .......
     .......

</LinearLayout>
```

Answer (score 0):

Use code like this:

Why you set a height and width Static/Fixed. Generally use a height and width "`wrapcontent`" or "`matchparent`"

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    tools:context=".MainActivity">

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        tools:layout_editor_absoluteX="8dp"
        tools:layout_editor_absoluteY="8dp">

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:orientation="horizontal"
            tools:layout_editor_absoluteX="8dp"
            tools:layout_editor_absoluteY="8dp">

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/TeamName4"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:gravity="center"
                android:text="Team 2 Name"
                android:textAppearance="@android:style/TextAppearance.Theme"
                android:textSize="20sp"
                android:textStyle="bold|italic" />

            <EditText
                android:id="@+id/TeamScore1"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:ems="10"
                android:gravity="center"
                android:inputType="number" />
        </LinearLayout>

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:orientation="horizontal"
            tools:layout_editor_absoluteX="8dp"
            tools:layout_editor_absoluteY="8dp">

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/TeamName2"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:gravity="center"
                android:text="Team 2 Name"
                android:textAppearance="@android:style/TextAppearance.Theme"
                android:textSize="20sp"
                android:textStyle="bold|italic" />

            <EditText
                android:id="@+id/TeamScore2"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:ems="10"
                android:gravity="center"
                android:inputType="numberSigned" />
        </LinearLayout>
    </LinearLayout>
</LinearLayout>
```